# How do I display the text data from Firestore (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have been watching YouTube videos but I am now lost since there is no videos on just displaying a single data as text, it is all about displaying data in a list.
Here is what I am trying to do

[Firestore Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk411.png)

I am trying to display just money.

Here is what I got so far.

```
child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 25),
                  Text(
                    'Current Balance',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('balance').snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        return Container(
                          child: Text(snapshot.data['money'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 35,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              )),
                        );
                      }),
                ],
              )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can fetch data from document

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('balance').doc('document_id').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        return Container(
          child: Text(snapshot.data.data()['money'],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 35,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )),
        );
      },
    );
```

If you don't know document Id then try this

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('balance').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        if (snapshot.data.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          return Container(
            child: Text(
              snapshot.data.docs[0].data()['money'],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 35,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Text('No Data');
        }
      },
    );
```